# How can I get keys from nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I have a javascript object with nested objects inside:

```
{
    "common": {
      "setting1": "Value 1",
      "setting2": 200,
      "setting3": true,
      "setting6": {
        "key": "value",
        "doge": {
          "wow": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "group1": {
      "baz": "bas",
      "foo": "bar",
      "nest": {
        "key": "value"
      }
    },
    "group2": {
      "abc": 12345,
      "deep": {
        "id": 45
      }
    }
  }
```

and I have to get all keys as nested array.

I've tried this function :

```
function getKeys(obj) {                                                                                                                                
  return Object.keys(obj).map((key, keys) => {                                                                                                      
    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') return key;                                                                                                    
    return [key, getKeys(obj[key])];                                                                                               
  });                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

And got this: //

```
[
  [ 'common', [ 'setting1', 'setting2', 'setting3', [Array] ] ],
  [ 'group1', [ 'baz', 'foo', [Array] ] ],
  [ 'group2', [ 'abc', [Array] ] ]
]
```

Instead of expected result like this:

```
    [
  [ 'common', [ 'setting1', 'setting2', 'setting3','setting6', ['key','doge', ['wow']],
  [ 'group1', [ 'baz', 'foo', ['nest', ['key'] ],
  [ 'group2', [ 'abc', 'deep', ['id'] ] ]
    ]
```

etc.

Help me please

Comment: The output looks correct? What’s wrong with it from your perspective? Are you running this on node?

Comment: Try to use `JSON.stringify(output)` to console.log the result again. nodejs prompt may not show all the details of a object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, it looks correct, but doesn't consider several nested objects.
It has to be insted of [array] - another one nested key. and yes, it's node

Comment: Why would `key` be in a separate array then `doge`?

Comment: @Nenad Vracar  my fault

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` on `Object.entries` and create a recursive function.

```js
const data = {"common":{"setting1":"Value 1","setting2":200,"setting3":true,"setting6":{"key":"value","doge":{"wow":""}}},"group1":{"baz":"bas","foo":"bar","nest":{"key":"value"}},"group2":{"abc":12345,"deep":{"id":45}}}

function getKeys(data) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
    r.push(key)
    if (typeof value === 'object') r.push(getKeys(value))
    return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(getKeys(data))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but it doesn't consider another one layout "wow"
it looks like :
[
  'common',
  [
    'setting1',
    'setting2',
    'setting3',
    'setting6',
    [ 'key', 'doge', [Array] ]
  ],
  'group1',
  [ 'baz', 'foo', 'nest', [ 'key' ] ],
  'group2',
  [ 'abc', 'deep', [ 'id' ] ]
]

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function getKeys (obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        const key = keys[i];
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            keys.splice(i+1, 0, getKeys(obj[key]));
            i++;
        }
    }
    return keys
}
```

result:

```
'["common",["setting1","setting2","setting3","setting6",["key","doge",["wow"]]],"group1",["baz","foo","nest",["key"]],"group2",["abc","deep",["id"]]]'
```

Not the most optimised solution probably but should work.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but it doesn't consider another one layout "wow"

it looks like :
[
  'common',
  [
    'setting1',
    'setting2',
    'setting3',
    'setting6',
    [ 'key', 'doge', [Array] ]
  ],
  'group1',
  [ 'baz', 'foo', 'nest', [ 'key' ] ],
  'group2',
  [ 'abc', 'deep', [ 'id' ] ]
]

Comment: I ran the code and included the result. This is the result you want, right?

Comment: You should use `JSON.stringify(getKeys(obj));` to check the result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, both options worked! I just had to add null check in `if (typeof obj[key] === 'object')` because of the TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
const keys = Object.keys(obj); (one of the values was null and "The typeof null returns 'object' , which is historical bug in JavaScript that may never be fixed.")